# React Native Generate Signed APK - :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease

Tags: android, react-native, build, apk, gradlew

I am trying to build an apk for my app in React Native but when I run
./gradlew assembleRelease at the end I got this error.

I don't even have an idea why this is happening.

Is there anyone that could help?

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/infer/annotation/Assertions.class

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-svg')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this might be because of the different version of the react-native dependency so I had changed it to fixed version.

```
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.0") { force = true }
```

And had changed all native library react-native version to the same as in my `build.gradle`(app)  that is **0.55.0** or whatever you are using but should have to be same in throughout the application.

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am using 0.56. Is there anything else you have done?

Comment: The version number was not the problem the problem with me was different version numbers in different build gradle files. Try to make the same everywhere.